Horror short film about a guy trying to test a VR game with spiders in a house. He wakes up and realizes the game hasn't started
It started when a guy was offered by a famous gaming company to test their new VR game. Some kind of computer chip was embedded to him and it looks like there's a matrix tube thing that needs to be inserted on the back of his neck. Also he drank something before the game starts (to get sleepy?). The game starts in a house and it looks the realest VR game. Then there were spiders appearing out of nowhere and some knocking scene.
The ending is when he woke up from the game (he was really really afraid) the game hasn't started yet, they said. after he drank the sleepy concoction he was asleep just for 1 min.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Was it live-action or animated?

it was on youtube, its live-action i forgot to say. the ending is when he woke up from the game (he was really really afraid) the game hasnt started yet they say. after he drank the sleepy concoction he was asleep just for 1 min

Can you [edit] that extra information into your question?

Shares some similarities to the Black Mirror episode “Playtest” but doesn’t end the same way, and isn’t a movie

@fez yooow youre right! This is it!

@naughtydog thanks for confirming! I've posted that as a formal answer, if you wouldn't mind accepting it, it'd be appreciated :)

This is the Black Mirror episode “Playtest”. Although it's an episode from a TV show, it's long enough to be mistaken for a short film. It matches a few of the points you remember; he's implanted with something in his neck, the VR game test, starting in a house, spiders.
Quoting from Wikipedia:

After his father dies from Alzheimer's disease, Cooper (Wyatt Russell) travels the world, ignoring phone calls from his mother. In London, he spends a night with the technology journalist Sonja (Hannah John-Kamen). He is forced to stay with her after his bank account is drained when he becomes victim to identity theft, but finds a paid offer to playtest a game for SaitoGemu.
At the company's building, he is met by Katie (Wunmi Mosaku) in an experiment room. Though she turns his phone off, he turns it back on to surreptitiously take pictures of the test kit for Sonja. Katie implants a small device called a "mushroom" in the back of his neck. He tests an augmented reality version of the game Whac-A-Mole. Cooper is impressed and agrees to a further test. He meets with Shou (Ken Yamamura), the company's owner, and is told that he will experience a horror game where an artificial neural network personalises the experience to his fears.
At Harlech House, the mansion he recognises from a SaitoGemu game, Cooper has an earpiece to communicate with Katie; there are also cameras throughout. After a while, he sees a spider and then a figure appearing in a painting. He hears footsteps and sees a simulation of Josh Peters (Jamie Paul), his childhood bully. In the kitchen, an enormous spider with Peters' face appears. Cooper's earpiece then ceases to work. Sonja arrives and urges Cooper to leave, but Cooper finds inconsistencies in her story. She stabs him and they fight. As her face inverts to a red skull, Cooper impales her on the knife lodged through his shoulder, and she, the knife, and Cooper's injury disappear.
Cooper awakens in Shou's office, the experiment having lasted only a single second and nothing subsequent having been real.

Spoilers for the ending:

 Cooper returns home to find his mother (Elizabeth Moynihan), who does not recognise him, dialling his number repeatedly. Back in the first experiment room, Cooper yells for his mother as the mushroom kills him. Cooper was in fact killed within 0.04 seconds by a phone call from his mother causing signal interference with the device, the subsequent experience existing only in his head.


That might be a clip from eXistenZ (1999) by David Cronenberg. It does feature VR games that are inserted into a port in the back of the neck of the player. It's been quite a while since I've seen it, so I'm not sure about the sleep medicine drink, but it does have the confusion about whether they're still in the game or not.

it is a fairly modern cgi. and also a short film. im pretty sure on the ending

No spiders in eXistenZ
